# Is possible to use openni with ROS jade?

Tags: kinect, openni, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently install the *Jade* version, so I want to use the openNI driver to use the Microsoft Kinect because this driver because it has a great performance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214064/is-possible-to-use-openni-with-ros-jade?/) by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2015-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it should be, but currently it seems you would have to compile it yourself because it seems to be not in the repository yet.

Regards,

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2015-07-21**:
Hi Christian thanks for your answer, I am not really sure how to build it by source. Is just to clone it in catkin_ws/src and then source the packages with source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash?.
And my other question is ...That packages really works on Jade version?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-22**:
Yes, that should be it.
And of course you need all the dependencies for the packages, you should be able to install them with rosdep:

http://answers.ros.org/question/75241/install-ros-dependencies-from-apt/